# unable to escape "?" in the url rewriting in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

`I have URL as: spa-shop/admin/index?docid=abc` ,For this URL i am using htacces Rewrite Rule.
The rule is as follow:

```
RewriteRule ^((?i)spa-shop)/(admin)/([a-zA-Z\?]*)$             spavendor/index.php?url=spaAdmin/$3 [L]
```

In this the output which i am expecting is : `spashop/index.php?url=spaAdmin/index?docid=abc` ,
but I am getting the URl as: `spashop/index.php?url=spaAdminShop/index`. Please let me know what is the problem though i am escaping the ? in the rewrite rule. But it seems not being escaped.

Comment: `?` is not part of the URI. Apache parses the query string separately so it won't ever be a member of the capture group. You'd need to separately URL encode the query string and append it to the rewrite.

Comment: separately URL encode the query string and append it to the rewrite. what this means as i am new to this. so have no idea of this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace your rule by this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(spashop)/admin/([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ $1/index.php?url=spaAdminShop/$2\?%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
urlencode($someURl)
```

This will encode ? to %3F

Comment: yes dude,  I did that so now my URL became spaendor/admin/index%3Fdocid=abc

Comment: but than also i m not getting what i expect.